# Avoid transition in CSS3 animation

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

Using this kind of simple animation :

```html
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .item {
        -webkit-animation: blink 2s linear 0 infinite;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes blink {
        from    { opacity: 0; }
        49.999% { opacity: 0; }
        50%     { opacity: 1; }
        to      { opacity: 1; }
    }
</style>

<div class="item">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

Is there a way to avoid the transition between `0%` and `50%`, without fixing a value at `49.999%` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, not really

All I can suggest to make your life easier is to shorten it to

```
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    0%, 49.999% { opacity: 0; }
    50%         { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Comment: I didn't found anything about it neither. Anyway, if your solution doesn't fit exactly to my answer, it allows me to drastically shorten my CSS, which is what I was looking for. Thanks for the tip !